# Algorithm for shortest paths with multiple origins

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have multiple origins (blue circles) and multiple destinations (green squares) as in the image below:
[image]

- I know the distance between each origin and destination.
- Each origin can only have a certain amount of destinations.

I want to find the most efficient combination of origins-destinations so that the total distances is at the minimum.

The only thing that comes to mind is some kind of Knapsack Problem variation, but I don't really know how to proceed because there is no constant "weight" (distance) for the items here.

Comment: Questions about algorithms are more suitable for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You want to cover all the destinations? or what do you mean by "combination of origins-destinations"?

Comment: I want to cover as much destinations as I have room for in origins, not necessarily covering all of them though.

Comment: So what has precedence: maximising the number of destinations or minimising the total distance?

Comment: maximizing the number of destinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a matrix `W` of distances where `W[i][j]` is the distance between origin `i` and destination `j`, you can formulate your problem as a binary integer program where `b[i][j]` is 1 if destination `j` is assigned to origin `i`, and 0 otherwise. If we fill to capacity

```
min sum_{i,j} w[i][j]*b[i][j]
subject to
sum_j b[i][j]=capacity[i] for all i (1)
sum_i b[i][j]<=1 for all j(2)
```

Constraint (1) says that every origin is filled to capacity. constraint (2) says that no destination is assigned to more than 1 origin.
If there is enough capacity to accomodate  all destinations  then solve

```
min sum_{i,j} w[i][j]*b[i][j]
subject to
sum_j b[i][j]<=capacity[i] for all i 
sum_i b[i][j]=1 for all j
```

I think this second formulation is a version of the [Multiple knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints).

So what you can do is check if this second formulation has a feasible solution, if not,
solve the first one. You can use a MIPS solver.